# Is there any other possible ways to fetch data from external webpages to develop a comparison-shopping website except using API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I am really sorry if my question is not appropriate but I could not find any other easy way to collect data from external websites except using API. I feel I am missing out on somethings but I am not sure what, I did search for the possible ways one can retrieve data but I could not understand. I am working with php and javascript at the moment and I'm looking for easier ways to obtain data from external sites into my site. I would really be really grateful if you can explain me about how to retrieving the data from external sources works.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a way, but it's much more risky as it's highly dependant on the HTML formatting of the page (i.e., if the layout of the site changes, it won't be working anymore). Just load the page you want to retrieve the informations from thanks to CURL and parse the HTML result (search for HTML parsers in PHP).

You'll have to tell your script in which HTML tag it should find the information though.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very big field in my opinion. I have been doing many hobby projects involving "scraping" to a degree. There exists many many tricks, every time you tackle a new website you have to use your creativity.

I don't think there exists a single guide for all.

There are two main things either website loads a content asynchronously using AJAX or website serves the content in the beginning in HTML.

If it is the second case it is very easy to obtain HTML and parse using `curl` and `regular expressions`

If it is the first case you have options but I think you can inspect the network calls in chrome to see where the actual data is downloaded. It might be for example in a JSON format which is very fortunate, or custom format which you have to reverse-engineer.

I can understand why it is very hard to get used to this kind of 'programming' since you have no control on the actual markup and you have to depend on many things. You should choose your assumptions in a way to maximize your scripts fault-tolerance.

Sorry if you were looking for a real basic tutorial on how to scrape data from a static content but this is a general explanation of what you might encounter.

I would suggest you to find a website which doesn't load content via AJAX and have a relatively nice HTML mark-up. Then use curl and regexps to scrape it then climb your way up from there collecting tricks on the way.

Note: You can choose some kind of DOM-analyzer or whatever they are called and use it instead of regular expressions, but I don't think they are extra necessary for a starter.

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you can use curl to fetch html from other websites. Check here http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Also check out, http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/, or http://cuab.de

You would also want to see this example http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-data-extractor.html

There are plenty libraries out there. Basically you fetch the web page as a big STRING and then you start looking for clues such as images or urls etc by parsing using string manipulation technics

Here is an example fetching images from a website http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/12/php-how-to-get-all-images-from-an-html-page/ .

Also consider that some website do not allow curl fopen due to security reasons. They don't want you to steal there work. There are also restrictions on the timing which you grab content from the website and a web server can block your ip because you are hoping from one url to another like crazy.

It is googles topic, a hackers topic and in general a very large scale scientific topic on how to crawl that huge graph called Internet.

Have fun and be carefull.